# Task scheduler to update local db with server db entries automatically in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I have a local database which I want to sync with server database automatically after suppose 1 day. Anybody knows how to code this through .net C#. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is run on IIS write  batch file that contains:

`start http://www.yourdomain.com/updateSql`

Where your script that handles the update to your database and is routed to the page **updateSql.cshtml** or **updateSql.aspx** where your script/logic resides or whichever you are using to generate this process which I am assuming ASP.NET.

If this isn't a website then use a similar approach where the application runs the process. Most likely you are going to create a standalone executable with the source that processes the database function and call it from the batch file.

Then of course you add the batch file to your server's task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Write a .net console app to run a parameterised stored procedure to get the data updates, invoke this console app via a scheduled task.

Ensure the app runs under the appropriate identity. Do plenty of logging off what your console app is doing for debugging and auditing.

Comment: no, but there wont be much business logic above and beyond validation and exception handling in your console app, the intelligence will be in your stored procedure to get the data delta.

Comment: @[dan m](http://stackoverflow.com/users/181221/dan-m) Typically here on stack overflow (SO) your questions have to be more specific and as [Prabhjot](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6577761/prabhjot) suggests, offer some code. Finally, when you ask a question and SO users are kind enough to answer your question you need to follow up the answers and eventually vote for the answer if provided. I suggest you read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @yardpenalty it wasnt my question - the question was vague, you cant expect someone to write an entire app for someone.

Comment: I apologize Dan, I had it backwards. I meant for my comment to be towards the individual asking the question. Sorry about that. I looked at his post about about asking for some code thinking you had asked the question. He was basically asking for you to share some code with the answer. Oops. Good answer btw. I'd vote for your answer as the right answer since I think he is writing a console app. Maybe...?